# Compiling Scheme using Java

Tags: java, compilation, scheme, code-generation

I was writing a Scheme interpreter (trying to be fully R5RS compatible) and it just struck me that compiling into VM opcodes would make it faster. (Correct me if I am wrong.)  I can *interpret* the Scheme source code in the memory, but I am stuck at understanding code generation.

My question is: What patterns will be required to generate opcodes from a parse tree, for, say, the JVM or any other VM (or even a real machine)? And what, if any, will be the complications, advantages, or disadvantage of doing so?

Comment: downvoter should care to comment atleast :-)

Comment: Did you have a look at [JScheme](http://jscheme.sourceforge.net/jscheme/main.html)?  It's worth noting that "JScheme implements all of R4RS Scheme except that continuations can only be used as escape procedures and strings are not mutable. JScheme is an open source project hosted at sourceforge.net."  Those bits about continuations were touched upon in SK-logic's answer, and the immutability of strings arises from Java interoperability (where strings are immutable).  If you're still looking at Scheme compilation, that's a good example to look at.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Scheme there will be two major complications related to JVM.

First, JVM does not support explicit tail calls annotations, therefore you won't be able to guarantee a *proper tail recursion* as required by R5RS (3.5) without resorting to an expensive mini-interpreter trick.

The second issue is with continuations support. JVM does not provide anything useful for implementing continuations, so again you're bound to use a mini-interpreter. I.e., each CPS trivial function should return a next closure, which will be then called by an infinite mini-interpreter loop.

But still there are many interesting optimisation possibilities. I'd recommend to take a look at Bigloo (there is a relatively fast JVM backend) and Kawa. For the general compilation techniques take a look at [Scheme in 90 minutes](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~boucherd/mslug/meetings/20041020/90-min-scc/90-min-scc.pdf).

And still, interpretation is a viable alternative to compilation (at least on JVM, due to its severe limitations and general inefficiency). See how SISC is implemented, it is quite an interesting and innovative approach.

Comment: I was reading SISC as well. But then again, how can I compile to any other machine code(perhaps a VM i implement that _can_ do proper continuations/tailrecursions?)

Comment: @Aniket, compiling for a specially tailored VM is trivial. Once you've done a CPS transform and lambda lifting (both covered in detail in "Scheme in 90 minutes"), just do a single pass expression flattening into a stack machine (after CPS you'll only have a trivial control flow). See http://bit.ly/I2LFdr for a simple example.

Comment: loook at Closure (http://clojure.org/), also a Lisp-like language - it compiles to JVM bytecode, and compiler is in open source.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov, Clojure is not very relevant - it does not require proper tail recursion and there are no first class continuations, so there is not much to learn from its implementation, besides trivial expression compilation and its nice and clean FFI.